# elementary OS Website Blog RSS feed

Tags: elementary-website

Is there a way to subscribe to elementary's official blog located at http://blog.elementary.io/? Email or RSS feed are preferred methods. elementary's blog looks like it's using Tumblr, but I would really like to avoid creating Tumblr account.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

the RSS url that you need is this: http://blog.elementary.io/rss